# SimpleDateFormat and DataFormat have different Time Zone

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, date-format

I have a problem with `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateFormat`. Although I have set the local time zone on both in Germany, different time zones are displayed.
The output is:

```
SimpleDateFormat:Tue May 01 00:00:00 CEST 2018
DateFromat: 26.05.18 08:46:24 MESZ
```

My code:

```
public class StringAndDateFormat {
    private static final int  dateStyleLoc = DateFormat.SHORT;
    private static final int timeStyleLoc= DateFormat.LONG;
    private static final Locale localeLoc = Locale.GERMANY;
    private static final String stringDateIni= "2000/01/01 00:00:00:";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getStringNow());
        System.out.println(getDateFromStringSimpleDateFormat("01.05.2018 00:00:00"));
    }

    public static String getStringNow() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(dateStyleLoc, timeStyleLoc, localeLoc);
        return  dateFormat.format(new Date());
    }

    public static Date getDateFromStringSimpleDateFormat(String stringDateIn) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatTmp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",localeLoc);
        Date dateTmp= null;

        try {

            dateTmp=  simpleDateFormatTmp.parse(stringDateIn);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dateTmp;
    }
```

Comment: Those are not different time zones. Those are different names for the same (half) time zone. *Mitteleuroåäische Sommerzeit* (MESZ) is known internationally as *Central European Summer Time* (CEST) (“half” because it is only used around 7 months of the year).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateFormat` classes. They are not only long outdated, they are also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: `getDateFromStringSimpleDateFormat` returns a `Date` (another outdated class that you should consider not using at all). A `Date` neither has any time zone, any format nor any locale in it. When you print it, its `toString` method is used. `toString` uses the computer’s time zone for rendering the string (this confuses many), so CEST comes from there and is not localized (not translated into Germany locale). BTW you are not setting any time zone anywhere in your code, despite what you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Locale localeLoc = Locale.GERMANY;
private static final ZoneId zoneLoc = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatterLoc = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT, FormatStyle.LONG)
        .withLocale(localeLoc);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getStringNow());
    ZonedDateTime parsedDateTime 
            = getDateFromStringDateTimeFormatter("01.05.2018 00:00:00");
    System.out.println(parsedDateTime);
    System.out.println(parsedDateTime.format(formatterLoc));
}

public static String getStringNow() {
    return ZonedDateTime.now(zoneLoc).format(formatterLoc);
}

public static ZonedDateTime getDateFromStringDateTimeFormatter(String stringDateIn) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatterTmp
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", localeLoc);
    return LocalDateTime.parse(stringDateIn, formatterTmp).atZone(zoneLoc);
}
```

Running this code just now it printed

```
26.05.18, 10:12:41 MESZ
2018-05-01T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
01.05.18, 00:00:00 MESZ
```

In your code you had set a locale (`GERMANY`) on both your `DateFormat` and your `SimpleDateFormat`. You had not set any time zone. Even though locale and time zone *may* both be associated with a geographical area (they aren’t always), they are not directly related, so setting one of them never affects the other. Furthermore, if you set a time zone and a locale on a `SimpleDateFormat`, none of them are reflected in the `Date` you get from its `parse` method since a `Date` can neither hold a time zone nor a locale. It’s just a point in time.

What happened instead was that both formats used your JVM’s time zone setting. `dateFormat` used `GERMANY` locale and therefore produced `MESZ` for Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit, the German name for Central European Summer Time. `simpleDateFormatTmp` used the same default time zone for interpreting your date-time string into a point in time, but as I said, didn’t store the time zone into the `Date`. When you printed the `Date`, you were implicitly invoking its `toString` method. This method again uses your JVM’s default time zone for generating the string. This fact confuses many. However, `toString` always uses English, so the day is “Tue” (for Tuesday), the month is “May” and the half time zone is “CEST” for Central European Summer Time, the same time zone that has been used all the way.

By the way, Central European Summer Time is not a true time zone. Rather it is the summer time aware name used for Central European Time during the roughly 7 months of the year where summer time is in effect (summer time is also known as daylight saving time or DST). Central European Time in turn is the common name for a large number of European time zones that share the same time these days, but have not always done and therefore cannot be considered identical.

In my code I used `ZonedDateTime` to hold a date. Contrary to `Date` and as its name suggests it *does* hold a time zone, thus seems to give you what you want. Its `toString` method renders the time zone as Europe/Berlin. To get MESZ, just use the same formatter as we used for the other string.

I do warmly recommend using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, throwing out the long outdated `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.